# VBA Shared Calendar Meeting Creator

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a modified code I found online, and I am having issues finding a shared calendar in outlook.

```
Sub SharedCalendarEventCreator()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outNameSpace As Namespace
Dim outSharedName As Outlook.Recipient
Dim outCalendarFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim r As Long
Dim eduSheet As Worksheet


On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Schedule").Activate
Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Set outNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.Folders("Lunch Calendar")
    Set outCalendarFolder = outCalendarFolder.Folders("Calendar")
    Set olAppItem = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

  r = 7

  Do Until Trim$(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
    With olAppItem
      .Subject = "SOF " & Cells(1, 2).Value & " " & Cells(2, 2).Value & " " & Cells(3, 2).Value & " " & Cells(r, 2).Value
      .Start = Cells(r, 1).Value
    vArray = Split(Cells(4, 2).Value2, ";")
    For Each vElement In vArray
      '.Recipients.Add .Recipients.Add(vElement)
      Next vElement
      .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
      .AllDayEvent = True
      .Body = Cells(r, 3).Value
      .ResponseRequested = False
      .Send
      r = r + 1
    End With
  Loop
Set olAppItem = Nothing
Set outCalendarFolder = Nothing
Set outNameSpace = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Picture of the Calendar location:

[image: Calendar Path]

I believe the issue is within these lines, but I have tried to change them without any luck:

```
Set outNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.Folders("Lunch Calendar")
Set outCalendarFolder = outCalendarFolder.Folders("Calendar")
Set olAppItem = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```

The error I received:

[image]

When I hit debug, this is the line it highlights:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Its not locating the Calendar. The error reads "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found." I added more info/pics to OP.

Comment: Try obtaining the calendar object in this way: `Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(9)` and comment `'Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.Folders("Lunch Calendar")` and  `'Set outCalendarFolder = outCalendarFolder.Folders("Calendar")`. What do you have in `cells(4, 2)`? mail addresses separated by ";"?

Comment: yes I have email address to send out the invite separated by ";". The invites go out correctly. Taking your suggestion it seems to run without an error, but how can I have the invite go on the "Lunch Calendar" Calendar? I think your suggestion is putting it on the default (my personal) calendar

Comment: With these two lines: **Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(9)** and uncommented
    **Set outCalendarFolder = outCalendarFolder.Folders("Lunch Calendar")** I get no error. When i use **Debug.Print outCalendarFolder.Name, outCalendarFolder.FolderPath** I get the correct file path: \\janedoe@gmail.com\Calendar\Lunch Calendar. But the events aren't being added to the calendar. Sorry - I don't know how to put lines into code brackets.

Comment: In order to format a code line, please place it between ``. The first key of the second keys row, just in front of the numeric keys (together with `~`). I did not need to use the code and did not even try it. I only know how to return the 'calendar' object and tried showing that. I observed/thought that the two code lines were used to `Set` it. So, does your code work as you need, now? If so, I will copy the code for eventually a future use... :)

Comment: No it is not working yet. I'll post the solution if it get it resolved

Answer (score 0):

Navigate the folder tree from "janedoe@gmail" to "Calendar" to "Lunch Calendar".

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SharedCalendarEventCreator()

    ' Early binding - Set reference to Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    
    Dim outMailboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim outCalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim outCalendarSubFolder As Outlook.Folder
    
    Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Set outNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set outMailboxFolder = outNameSpace.Folders("janedoe@gmail")
    Set outCalendarFolder = outMailboxFolder.Folders("Calendar")
    Set outCalendarSubFolder = outCalendarFolder.Folders("Lunch Calendar")
        
    'Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = outCalendarSubFolder
    
    Set olAppItem = outCalendarSubFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    olAppItem.Display
    
    Set olAppItem = Nothing
    Set outCalendarSubFolder = Nothing
    Set outCalendarFolder = Nothing
    Set outMailboxFolder = Nothing
    Set outNameSpace = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```